# J query ajax, Getting undefined values

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm still trying to solve it for few days. I've tried lots of stuff but no one worked:

Here is the code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#buttonclick").click(function () {
        var myval = {
            FirstName: $('#TxtFirstNamePhysician').val(),
            LastName: $('#TxtLastNamePhysician').val(),
            EmailId: $('#TxtEmailIdPhysician').val(),
            Password: $('#TxtPasswordPhysician').val(),
            PhoneNumber: $('#TxtPhoneNoPhysician').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:49956/Physician_Registration/Physician_Reg",
            type: 'POST',
            data: myval,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.responseText);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It says undefined.

[This Is what is the error i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z42bu.png)

Comment: I deduce that your AJAX call succeeds because you say it 'says' undefined (you mean alert?), and the error callback alerts two times. So if you get undefined, it means the data object of the success callback does not have any attribute called responseText.

Comment: What is undefined exactly ? And when ?

Comment: it showing like,FirstName: undefined, LastName: undefined, EmailId: undefined like it goes..when clicking a button with id buttonclick

Comment: See the Image .

Comment: show us the relevant HTML as it seems the ids are not matching

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli I am Trying to Call A WEB API Using this ajax

Answer (score 0):

Try by passing correct content type.
If not worked then try it by converting your myval object to json. and pass the content type as application/json.

Comment: Can you Please Give me the Code?

Comment: $("#buttonclick").click(function () {
        var myval = {
            'FirstName': $('#TxtFirstNamePhysician').val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:49956/Physician_Registration/Physician_Reg",
            type: 'POST',
            data: myval,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.responseText);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
    });

Comment: @Abhi forgot to include contenttype:"application/json"

Comment: @Abhi please check you textbox value in console $('#TxtFirstNamePhysician').val() if still not working then send here code.

Comment: It seems that you've a problem with id's you are using to select the html elements. Make sure the i'd are assigned at the right place

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's due to your html is not markup properly.

I've make a working sample, go to the following jsfiddle.

```
<body>
<form>
<label for="first-name">First Name</label>
<input name="first-name" id="TxtFirstNamePhysician" /><br>
<label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
<input name="last-name" id="TxtLastNamePhysician" /><br>
<label for="email">Email</label>
<input name="email" id="TxtEmailIdPhysician" /><br>
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="TxtPasswordPhysician" /><br>
<label for="phone-number">Phone Number</label>
<input name="phone-number" id="TxtPhoneNoPhysician" /><br>
<input type="button" value="submit" id="buttonclick" />
</form>
<div class="output">
</div>
</body>
```

[Working Sample in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/malcolmkee/v9p3ej95/8/)

Comment: Can you clarify it's not working where? Have you tried the JSFiddle sample? I just confirmed it's working fine.

Comment: Yes JSFiddle Is working...but in my side i am using regular expression and required field validation

Comment: The validation and regular expression is in the js? Can you share those code as well?